# How to access the other scripts list values in current script in python

Tags: python

I have a script1.py

```
import sys
lst = []
for v in range(1,int(len(sys.argv)),1):
   lst.append(sys.argv[v])
```

script2.py

```
from script1 import lst
print lst
```

if I execute the python `script2.py abc xyz`, it just gives the output as `[]` (an empty list).

How can I achieve this, please help me.

Comment: There's a preview option when entering a question, and code block formatting. Please use it to make your question more readable.

Comment: `lst = sys.argv[1:]` would be a lot easier to write than that convoluted for loop.

Comment: I want to access the list values (lst varibale) in script2.py

Comment: Works fine for me. I did alter your original code: `from script1 import lst`. Since your code with `from script import lst` didn't fail with an importerror, you probably have another file `script.py` lying around, and you failed to spot the typo.

Comment: I am not sure where is wrong.
this is what I am executing
script1.py
'import sys
lst = []
print "I am in script1"
for v in range(1,int(len(sys.argv)),1):
   lst.append(sys.argv[v])'
script2.py
`from script1 import lst
print lst`

output:

I am in script1
[]

Answer (score -2):

//---
You import just lst variable, because of `from script import lst`. So, code does not execute, and you have lst = []. Make another approach, probably list comprehension would be ok.
//---
Oh, terribly sorry, my fault. It's wrong concept, script does execute fully. So, problem lies in another field.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer , i didnt get you.